# psql query CASE vs Multiple select for a large data-sets - performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

For large datasets which option is better multiple select vs case

**CASE EXAMPLE:**

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN(created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as day_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN(created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as month_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN(created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as quater_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN(created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 months')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as half_year_count,
SUM(CASE WHEN(created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 years')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as year_count,
count(*) as total_count from wallets;
```

**Multiple Select Query:**

```
SELECT count(*) from wallets where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days';
SELECT count(*) from wallets where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months';
SELECT count(*) from wallets where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months';
SELECT count(*) from wallets where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 months';
SELECT count(*) from wallets where created_at > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 years';
SELECT count(*) from wallets;
```

the requirements are to find wallets count by day, month, 3 months, 6 months and year.
If I go with multiple select then 6 queries will be needed to fetch the data.

using switch case we can get the data in a single query but I am not sure its a best practice to use switch case for large datasets.

Please find the query analysis below, I have only 10 records in my DB:

**Case query Analysis:**

[image]

**Multiple query Analysis:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the two and compared the differences in execution time? What is your observation?

Comment: @KaushikNayak have added the execution time analysis.

Comment: @Ben he has included `SELECT count(*) from wallets;` and `count(*) as total_count from wallets` in both queries so I think he is interested in whole data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single query is going to be better.  You will get an improvement in performance using `filter`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days')) as day_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'))  as month_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months')) as quater_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 months')) as half_year_count,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE created_at > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 years')) as year_count,
       COUNT(*) as total_count 
FROM wallets;
```

If you have an index on `created_at`, then this should also help Postgres optimize to only use that index.

Comment: Have tested the query for arround 1 Million records and this and Case query works awesome.
Thanks! @@gordon-linoff

Answer (score 0):

From knex point of view the difference is that multiple queries can be sent to the DB through separate connections and executed parallel. Doing just single query is probably more performant overall causing less stress / data transfer overhead on DB server.

Biggest drawback from first way of doing the query is that you cannot build it nicely with knex and it looks horrible to anyone who reads the code.

Better way to achieve this kind of packing multiple queries to single is to use postgres `with` statement (common table expressions) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html which knexalso supports http://knexjs.org/#Builder-with

EDIT: or just do multiple queries in single select somewhat like Gordon Linoff suggested :

```
knex
  .select( 
    knex('wallets')
      .where('createad_at', '>', knex.raw("CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 days'"))
      .count()
      .as('lastDay'),
    knex('wallets')
      .where('createad_at', '>', knex.raw("CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 months'"))
      .count()
      .as('lastMonth'),
      ... rest of the queries ...
  );
```

https://runkit.com/embed/wsy01ar1hb73

postgresql should be able to optimize multiple subqueries to be executed with similair plan that Gordon's answer promotes.

Answer (score 0):

I can do an educated guess. Without an actual data tests are of little use.

The **Multiple Select Query** is easier to optimise by database planar. The PostgreSQL 9.6+ could use [index only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) for this. It may end in a few very fast queries.

The **Case Example** is very hard to read. I’m afraid nobody can write an index for this and the query will be forced to scan the whole table. This could be a horribly slow operation.